# make ls gray out files that end with tilde (`~`) using `LS_COLOR`

Tags: ls, colors, appearance

**Problem:** I am trying to modify `LS_COLORS` to gray out all files ending with the tilde character.

**Question:** Can anybody spot my mistake?

**Here is what I did:**

```
# write dircolors file:
dircolors -p > ~/.dircolors

# add a line
echo >> ~/.dircolors
echo ".*~ 01;34" >> ~/.dircolors

# apply changes to LS_COLOR
eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)"
```

Now, when I do

```
echo $LS_COLORS
```

I get a long line with the following begin and end:

```
rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36: ... *.xspf=00;36:*.*~=01;34:
```

So I would assume, that files ending with tilde (`~`) appear in the same color as directories (specified by `di`), but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you can't do this with `dircolors`, but you can do it by modifying `LS_COLORS` directly:

```
eval "$(dircolors)"
LS_COLORS="${LS_COLORS}*~=01;34:"
export LS_COLORS
```

`dircolors` only seems to handle three types of descriptors: terminal names (starting with `TERM`), file types (*e.g.* `DIR`), and extensions starting with `.`. The latter get expanded by prefixing them with `*`; so your `.*~` becomes `*.*~`, which only matches backup files containing a `.`. `ls` itself can interpret more general `LS_COLORS` entries such as `*~`, which matches all files ending with `~`.